# How to extend an existing Protocol in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

How to properly extend an existing Protocol in Elixir?

So that for example: `Poison.encode!(:null)` returns "null".

Take the `Poison.Encoder` Protocol as an example. I would like to make one addition to the Protocol for `Atom`. But I do not know how to do that without redefining everything in this Protocol.

```
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Atom do
  alias Poison.Encoder

  def encode(nil, _),   do: "null"
  def encode(true, _),  do: "true"
  def encode(false, _), do: "false"

  # /------------------------------------------------------
  # V My addition - What is the correct way of doing this?
  def encode(:null, _), do: "null"

  def encode(atom, options) do
    Encoder.BitString.encode(Atom.to_string(atom), options)
  end
end
```

#### Backstory

Hi, I was having a particular problem with JSON encoding, that lead me to that question.

I want that all `:null` Atoms are encoded as `null` in JSON, instead of the default `"null"` (as string). The JSON library I am using is `Poison`.

Now, the above works, but it spits out *warnings* like:

```
warning: redefining module Poison.Encoder.Atom (current version loaded from _build/dev/lib/poison/ebin/Elixir.Poison.Encoder.Atom.beam)
  lib/atom_encoder.ex:19
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to extend an existing protocol in Elixir. The possible workarounds would be:

**1.** Consider using something like `%Null{}` instead of `:null` atom and implement `Poison.Encoder` for this particular structure (I was unable to use [`@derive`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html#deriving) for that purpose):

```rb
defmodule Null do
  # @derive [Poison.Encoder] # that won’t work
  defstruct [json: "null"]

  def encode(%Null{json: json}), do: json
end
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Null do
  def encode(%Null{} = null), do: Null.encode(null)
end
```

**2.** One might force-reload the `Poison.Encoder` from your source using Erlang’s [`:code.delete/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#delete-1) and [`:code.purge/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#purge-1) (not recommended) before loading your module and [optionally] reinforce the consolidation with [`Protocol.consolidate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Protocol.html#consolidate/2):

```rb
:code.ensure_loaded(Poison.Encoder)
Protocol.assert_protocol!(Poison.Encoder)
:code.ensure_loaded(Poison.Encoder.Atom)
:code.delete(Poison.Encoder.Atom)
:code.purge(Poison.Encoder.Atom)

# your implementation
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Atom do
  ...
end
```

Comment: If using a different value for `:null` is an option, why not just use `nil`?

Comment: @Dogbert there could be a necessity to explicitly distinguish `nil` and `:null` within a project code.

Comment: @mudasobwa a few things in your answer: (1) You probably meant to `Poison.Encoder` instead of `Poison.Encode` (there is no module `Poison.Encode`). (2) This works in dev, but it will fail within a release, as there will be two definitions of this Poison.Encoder. Have you check if there is a way to include this in a release?

Comment: (1) fixed, yes, thx, it was a typo. (2) I did not, since it’s a nasty hack in general, but I believe `:code.purge` will effectively purge the original implementation from the VM.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to reimplement protocols for builtin types. Other packages you're using might rely on the original behavior of the implementation. I'd go with a function that recursively replaces all `:null` values with `nil` and then pass that to `Poison.encode`. You can make a wrapper function which does this transform and then calls `Poison.encode` if you want. Here's a basic implementation of this:

```
defmodule A do
  def null_to_nil(:null), do: nil
  def null_to_nil(list) when is_list(list) do
    Enum.map(list, &null_to_nil/1)
  end
  def null_to_nil(map) when is_map(map) do
    Enum.map(map, fn {k, v} -> {k, null_to_nil(v)} end) |> Map.new
  end
  def null_to_nil(term), do: term
end

IO.inspect A.null_to_nil([1, 2, :null, %{a: :null, b: %{b: [:null, :null]}}])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, nil, %{a: nil, b: %{b: [nil, nil]}}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. Absolutely, and I know how to recursively replace `:null` with `nil`. Yet I do not want to take that performance penalty of walking a potentially very large list or tree twice just to do this conversion.

Comment: I posted this question, since I thought there might be a way to **extend** a Protocol, as opposed to _redefine_ it.

If it is conceptually not a good idea, and forbidden, well so be it.

Comment: Thinking further about your proposal: Might there be a way to append this conversion somehow in-line with the JSON encoding Poison is doing?

I am thinking of something that can happen within the list/tree walking that Poison has to do either way.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. If performance is this important, I believe your best bet would be to delete and redefine the `Poison.Encoder` implementation for atoms as suggested by @mudasobwa.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and consideration.